# Separate bashrc file for ssh sessions to avoid Unison Errors

Tags: shell, bashrc, synchronization, rc, unison

Recently my Unison started throwing up some strange error whenever I tried to sync between my laptop and my PC. I realized that I had added a line in `bashrc` that would print my pending tasks whenever I would open a terminal.

The line added in my `bashrc`:

```
task list  #this command comes from a small utility called taskwarrior
```

The error is here:

```
Received unexpected header from the server:
 expected "Unison 2.40\n" but received "\nID Proj     Age Description\n-- -------- --- -----------------------------\n 2          11d Do the research work\n 3 Life     11d Get stickynotes from stationary\n 1 Technical 11d Fix the error\n\n3 tasks\n", 
which differs at "\n".
This can happen because you have different versions of Unison
installed on the client and server machines, or because
your connection is failing and somebody is printing an error
message, or because your remote login shell is printing
something itself before starting Unison.
```

As mentioned in the error log, `my login shell is printing something itself before starting Unison`. This is indeed the root of the problem.

So, now I have 2 questions:

1. How do I make my bashrc to print "task-list" message AFTER the Unison header? Alternatively, can I make the ssh sessions to load separate RC file so that the "task-list" is not printed at all?
2. Will it be safe to print anything at all? I mean if I am somehow manage to print my task-list after the Unison header, is their any chance of data corruption during syncing, due to the additional information in the header?

PS: Unison uses ssh for communication between the two systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the output of the script (i.e. rc file) is a terminal if not; if it is it should be safe to output text, and if not a terminal don't output anything:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    # check your jobs here and print any info you want to see
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the current is interactive by searching for `i` in `$-`:

```bash
if expr "$-" : '.*i' >/dev/null; then
    echo interactive
fi
```

Comment: Yep. This works too :)